# Is it possible to pass an expression to the value attribute of an input tag?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I tried the following, but the input field is blank.

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label>First name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John" formControlName="firstname" value="{{this.session_user[0].firstName}}">
</div>
```

Comment: can you please explain a little bit more clearly what you actually want? Do you want to have a default value in your input?

Comment: You can use the formControl to do this..

Comment: The form updates the user information in the database and I don't want to write everything all over again (beacause the form is empty). I was wondering if I could fill the input with the data from the session_user variable.

Comment: what is you requirement can you please expalin that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I understood you want to set a default value to a FormControl value, I suppose your code is like this

```
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

    public form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['This is the default value', // Default value
        [
          Validators.required // Validators here if needed
        ]
      ]
    });
```

To set a default value using FormBuilder, you can do it like the example above, of course, it can be a variable.

If you don't have the value yet when defining the FormGroup you can set the value whenever you want like so

```
    this.form.setValue({ firstname: "New value" });
```

Please note that the code above won't work if your input element is not inside a form element like in the example below

```
<form class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
          <label>First name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="John" formControlName="firstname">
</form>
```

No need to set a value attribute to the input element.

If you do not want to use FormControl then you can use ngModel

```
<input type="text" placeholder="John" [(ngModel)]="session_user[0].firstName">
```